# Favourite tapas bars in Barcelona

Tags: spain

My fiancée and I are visiting Barcelona later this year for the second time and are keen to hit some of the best tapas bars that the city has to offer. What are your favourite tapas bars that you've been to in Barcelona and why?

Cheers,

Caps

Comment: Hello and welcome travel.SE. This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favourite - and I've spent a week in Barcelona four different times - is Ciudad Condal which doesn't have its name on a sign so you need to know the address, 18 Las Ramblas. Three of us arrived here and fought our way inside through the crowd to reach the maitre-d', (it doesn't take reservations) who asks if you want to eat "inside, outside, or at the bar?" and then told us it would be 30 minutes for our inside table. The next step is you go to the bar, ask for "tres cervesas por favor" and then point at something from the dozens of plates of gorgeous tapas and montaditos (thingies on toast) and say "tres". Presto - three beers and three (in our case) smoked salmon on toast and you go stand on the sidewalk with the rest of the city. Heaven. The beer was good, the salmon divine, and it didn't even feel like waiting. In no time we had our inside table and then the fun begins. Not a false note - and we gave them lots of opportunities because we ordered a lot of plates. Highly recommended, and actually cost less than some other dinners we had here even though we could barely move by the time we'd finished eating it all.